# Boot goes straight into Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu, how do I get back into Ubuntu and get the option of either at start up?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 from a DVD (all the files were there) onto my HP laptop. It used to be Windows 8 but a friend of mine put windows 7 on it instead so secure boot and fast boot are disabled. Ubuntu installed but now on start up it goes straight to Windows. I don't know how to get back onto Ubuntu as if I leave the DVD in the options are to "Install Ubuntu, try demo (something like that), OEM for manufacturers or exit."

I saw articles on here about fixing this from the Ubuntu terminal but if I can't get Ubuntu to load (because I tried the solution in the demo and it didn't work.) How do I go about this?

Literally spent last 4 hours trying to figure this out and I'm sure I'm coming across as a total noob but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: After adding the Boot Repair PPA, you need to go in and change the distribution from `trusty` to `saucy`. This is because there is no package for `trusty`. To do this, run `nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list` and change the references of `trusty` to `saucy`.